# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error:

Tags: ios, core-data

This code causes a crash with error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.

```
self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
NSLog(@"point one");
NSString *yourTrip=@"trip1";
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"thetrip== %@", yourTrip];

[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"thetrip" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];

[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *array = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (array == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"problemo");
}
```

The crash specifically happens after the NSError *error =nil;

Comment: And, do you have an entity called `thetrip`? Log the entity description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your

```
NSLog(@"problemo");
```

for a

```
NSLog(@"problemo %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

in order to have more information about what the error was.

I think (as well as @Wain) that you might not have an entity called 'thetrip' (maybe theTrip? be aware that Core Data is case sensitive). The log with the localized description will give you some hints about your problem.

Comment: The attribute name is thetrip and I logged the localized description and it had the value of yourtrip (trip1) but I never gets to NSLog(@"problemo %@", [error localizedDescription]); it crashed before that.

Comment: If this is happening in the simulator, try deleting the app from the simulator device, perform a project clean and try your app again.

Comment: Tried that multiple times and it crashes the exact same way with error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'

Comment: Can you check if self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy]; is returning an error. Maybe this line is raising the exception.